# How can I transfer players to the app store rating page?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to encourage players to create a rating/review of my game. For example, after a player completed 5 levels in my game, he/she gets ask if he/she wants to create a rating/review now. If they accept and click on the "Yes" button, then the Apple App Store or Google Play Store page of my game should get opened in the browser so that they can create a rating/review.

How can I open the Apple App Store or Google Play Store page of my game so that a player can create a rating?

Is it possible to create a rating if the application is still in beta mode in the app store?

Comment: You can use this library too: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.StoreReview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using [Share Plugin](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin) and [Device Info](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/deviceinfoplugin) , The sample code as bellow:

```
var url = string.Empty;
var appId = string.Empty;

if(CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform == Platform.iOS)
{
    appId = "your_id";
    url = $"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id={appId}&amp;onlyLatestVersion=true&amp;pageNumber=0&amp;sortOrdering=1&amp;type=Purple+Software"
}
else if(CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform == Platform.Android)
{
    appId = "your_id";
    url = $"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={appId}"
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
  return;

await CrossShare.Current.OpenBrowser(url, new BrowserOptions
{
    UseSafariWebViewController = false
);
}
```

> Is it possible to create a rating if the application is still in beta mode in the app store?

I think it's possible .

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created your Intent and set the extra info, call startActivity() to send it to the system. If the system identifies more than one activity that can handle the intent, it displays a dialog (sometimes referred to as the "disambiguation dialog") for the user to select which app to use, as shown in figure 1. If there is only one activity that handles the intent, the system immediately starts it.

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Good answer, I started to write one but yours gives more explainations. Hope it'll help him